# Hot to cancel the opening of a modal window in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my angular app I have a grid on which I have a button to show the details about the current row. I get the detailed data via $http to a sql database, and when the data is fetched correctly I open a modal window to show the details. What I want is to prevent the opening of the modal window if there was an error (http status code NOT FOUND for example). My code goes as follows:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/views/konto/kontoCrud.htm',
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true,
    windowClass: 'szpModal fade in',
    controller: 'KontoCrudCtrl',
    resolve: {
        konto: function () {
            if ($scope.mode === "new") {
                return { mode: mode,
                    sifra: "",
                    naziv: ""
                };
            } else {
                //console.log($scope.selectedItem);
                var result = kontoFactory.getKonto($scope.selectedItem[0].id);
                console.log(result);
                if (result.status === "OK") {
                    return result;
                } else {
                    toastr.error("Error fetching data!");
                    **// HERE I WANT TO CANCEL THE OPENING OF THE WINDOW AS 
                    // THE RECORD WAS NOT FOUND**
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you access the native `$scope.close()` implemented with ui-bootstrap modal at this point?

Comment: @glepetre. I tried this already, but I get the following error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'close'. I also tried $scope.$close as in the angular-ui this is stated about the modal window: In addition the scope associated with modal's content is augmented with 2 methods: * $close(result) * $dismiss(reason) Those methods make it easy to close a modal window without a need to create a dedicated controller.         I can't get this working, just don't know how to do it.

Comment: is there any permanent solution for this ? all answer mentioned below are work around ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the solution of the problem that you have, however a workaround.

On the click of the button call the factory method first and if it is ok then open the modal, otherwise dont.

```
var result = kontoFactory.getKonto($scope.selectedItem[0].id);
console.log(result);
if (result.status === "OK") {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/views/konto/kontoCrud.htm',
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true,
    windowClass: 'szpModal fade in',
    controller: 'KontoCrudCtrl',
    resolve: {
        konto: function () {
            if ($scope.mode === "new") {
                return { mode: mode,
                    sifra: "",
                    naziv: ""
                };
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
});
} else {
    toastr.error("Error fetching data!");
}
```

Comment: Can't do that. I use the resolve property to load the data before the window is opening to avoid flickering of the page.

Comment: You can return a callback from the http call and in that callback open the modal. This wont give you the flickering of the page.

Comment: Your solution does work, thought it's not exactly what I had in mind. So, the correct answer is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Think in a different way:

```
var openModal = function(konto){

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/views/konto/kontoCrud.htm',
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        windowClass: 'szpModal fade in',
        controller: 'KontoCrudCtrl',
        resolve: {
            konto: function () {
                return konto;
            }
        }
}    
 if ($scope.mode === "new") {
    openModal({ mode: mode,
            sifra: "",
            naziv: ""
        });

    } else {
        //console.log($scope.selectedItem);
        var result = kontoFactory.getKonto($scope.selectedItem[0].id);
        console.log(result);
        if (result.status === "OK") {
            openModal(result);
        } else {
            toastr.error("Error fetching data!");
            // THE RECORD WAS NOT FOUND**
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done, I defined a small controller for the modal (I'm also using the modal into my own controller). Applied to your case:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/views/konto/kontoCrud.htm',
  backdrop: true,
  keyboard: true,
  windowClass: 'szpModal fade in',
  //change the controller
  controller: function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.$close();
    };
  },
  // here I used modalInstance.result.then(function() {});
  // but resolve should work too
  resolve: {
    konto: function () {
      if ($scope.mode === "new") {
        return { mode: mode,
                sifra: "",
                naziv: ""
        };
      } else {
        //console.log($scope.selectedItem);
        var result = kontoFactory.getKonto($scope.selectedItem[0].id);
        console.log(result);
        if (result.status === "OK") {
          return result;
        } else {
          toastr.error("Error fetching data!");
          // call you close function
          $scope.closeModal();
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: I get this error when running your code: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'closeModal'. Obviously the methode is only visible in the child scope.

Comment: Which child scope? I am missing something. If you write `controller: function(){...}` without args, do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your getKonto function of your factory is like this:

```
function getKonto(id) {
  return $http.get('/youService/getKonto/' + id).then(function (response) {
     if (response.status === 200) {
         return response.data;
     } else {
         throw new Error("Something happened!");
     }
  });
}
```

Then within your else statement you should be doing something like this:

```
kontoFactory.getKonto($scope.selectedItem[0].id)
   .then(function (result) {
      //OPEN YOUR MODAL HERE
   })
   .catch (function (error) {
      //PROVISION TO SHOW YOUR ERROR HERE
   });
```

Comment: Yes, this is how I did it finally, but I wanted to use the "resolve" method when initiating the modal window.